# Search form using WP_User_Query

Tags: wordpress, search

Is it possible to create a custom search form using the WP_User_Query?

I'm calling  users into a page at the moment with specific information called for each one, but ideally what I'd like it to be is a search form where I can search for a user and their information then appears below, instead of having to find them in the big list using pagination.

It's a page within the admin area too, which adds another level onto it, I've created a very basic plugin with one page which will display this information. This is my link with what i have working at the moment - http://focusedlearning.hcrlaw.com/courses-admin

The pagination is working fine on this external page but in the actual admin area it isn't which is another problem I'm facing, but probably another question to this one!

If anyone has any ideas/places they can point me to it would be much appreciated, The code I have at the moment is below, but probably irrelevant at the moment,

Thanks in advance!

```
            <?php $total_users = count_users();
            $total_users = $total_users['total_users'];
            $paged = get_query_var('paged');
            $number = 20;?>

            <?php 
                $args = array(
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    'orderby' => 'display_name',
                    'count_total' => 'true',
                    'role' => 'subscriber',
                    'offset' => $paged ? ($paged) * $number : 0,
                    'number' => $number,
                );?>



                <?php
                    $blogusers = get_users($args);?>

                        <?php // Array of WP_User objects.
                            foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {?>

                <?php $userId = $user->ID;?>

                <?php  echo '<input type="text" value="' . esc_html( $user->display_name ) . '">';?>



                <div id="content">

                    <h2>Completed Courses</h2>


                <!-- COMPLIANCE-->



                    <?php
                        $post_args = array(
                            'post_type' => 'tribe_events',
                            'eventDisplay'=>'custom',
                            'start_date'     => date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( '-365 days' ) ),
                            'tax_query' => array(

                                array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'tribe_events_cat',
                                    'field'    => 'slug',
                                    'terms'    => 'compliance',
                                    ),
                                        ),

                                        'meta_query' => array(
                                            array(
                                                'key' => 'associated_people',
                                                'value' => '"' . $userid . '"', // matches exaclty "123", not just 123. This prevents a match for "1234"
                                                'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                        )
                                    )
                                ); ?>

                    <!-- MEMBERSHIP A -->                       

                    <?php if( rcp_is_active() && 2 == rcp_get_subscription_id() ) : ?>

                        <?php
                        $post_list = new wp_query( $post_args ); ?>

                            <table style="width:100%">      
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Compliance</td>
                                </tr>

                                <?php
                                    if( $post_list->have_posts() ) : while( $post_list->have_posts() ) : $post_list->the_post();
                                ?>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
                                        <td><?php the_field('cpd_credits'); ?></td>
                                    </tr>

                    <?php endwhile; else : ?>
                    <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>


                    <?php

                    $total_credit = 0;

                    $post_list = new wp_query( $post_args ); ?>

                    <table style="width:100%">      

                        <?php
                            if( $post_list->have_posts() ) : while( $post_list->have_posts() ) : $post_list->the_post();
                                $cur_credit = get_field('cpd_credits');
                                $total_credit += $cur_credit;
                        ?>


                        <?php endwhile; else : ?>
                        <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

                        <tr>
                            <td <?php if($total_credit >= 2): ?> style="background-color:#009137;" <?php endif; ?> <?php if($total_credit < 2): ?> style="background-color:#f50c1a;" <?php endif; ?>>
                                Total: <?php echo $total_credit;?> of 2 in the last 12 months
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        </table>

                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <!-- END OF MEMBERSHIP A -->


                        <!-- MEMBERSHIP B -->                       

                    <?php if( rcp_is_active() && 3 == rcp_get_subscription_id() ) : ?>

                        <?php
                        $post_list = new wp_query( $post_args ); ?>

                            <table style="width:100%">      
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Compliance</td>
                                </tr>

                                <?php
                                    if( $post_list->have_posts() ) : while( $post_list->have_posts() ) : $post_list->the_post();
                                ?>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
                                        <td><?php the_field('cpd_credits'); ?></td>
                                    </tr>

                    <?php endwhile; else : ?>
                    <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>


                    <?php

                    $total_credit = 0;

                    $post_list = new wp_query( $post_args ); ?>

                    <table style="width:100%">      

                        <?php
                            if( $post_list->have_posts() ) : while( $post_list->have_posts() ) : $post_list->the_post();
                                $cur_credit = get_field('cpd_credits');
                                $total_credit += $cur_credit;
                        ?>


                        <?php endwhile; else : ?>
                        <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

                        <tr>
                            <td <?php if($total_credit >= 2): ?> style="background-color:#009137;" <?php endif; ?> <?php if($total_credit < 2): ?> style="background-color:#f50c1a;" <?php endif; ?>>
                                Total: <?php echo $total_credit;?> of 2 in the last 12 months
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        </table>

                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <!-- END OF MEMBERSHIP B -->

                        <!-- MEMBERSHIP C -->                       

                    <?php if( rcp_is_active() && 4 == rcp_get_subscription_id() ) : ?>

                        <?php
                        $post_list = new wp_query( $post_args ); ?>

                            <table style="width:100%">      
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Compliance</td>
                                </tr>

                                <?php
                                    if( $post_list->have_posts() ) : while( $post_list->have_posts() ) : $post_list->the_post();
                                ?>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
                                        <td><?php the_field('cpd_credits'); ?></td>
                                    </tr>

                    <?php endwhile; else : ?>
                    <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>


                    <?php

                    $total_credit = 0;

                    $post_list = new wp_query( $post_args ); ?>

                    <table style="width:100%">      

                        <?php
                            if( $post_list->have_posts() ) : while( $post_list->have_posts() ) : $post_list->the_post();
                                $cur_credit = get_field('cpd_credits');
                                $total_credit += $cur_credit;
                        ?>


                        <?php endwhile; else : ?>
                        <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

                        <tr>
                            <td <?php if($total_credit >= 2): ?> style="background-color:#009137;" <?php endif; ?> <?php if($total_credit < 2): ?> style="background-color:#f50c1a;" <?php endif; ?>>
                                Total: <?php echo $total_credit;?> of 2 in the last 12 months
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        </table>

                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <!-- END OF MEMBERSHIP C -->

                        <!-- MEMBERSHIP D -->                       

                    <?php if( rcp_is_active() && 5 == rcp_get_subscription_id() ) : ?>

                        <?php
                        $post_list = new wp_query( $post_args ); ?>

                            <table style="width:100%">      
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Compliance</td>
                                </tr>

                                <?php
                                    if( $post_list->have_posts() ) : while( $post_list->have_posts() ) : $post_list->the_post();
                                ?>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
                                        <td><?php the_field('cpd_credits'); ?></td>
                                    </tr>

                    <?php endwhile; else : ?>
                    <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>


                    <?php

                    $total_credit = 0;

                    $post_list = new wp_query( $post_args ); ?>

                    <table style="width:100%">      

                        <?php
                            if( $post_list->have_posts() ) : while( $post_list->have_posts() ) : $post_list->the_post();
                                $cur_credit = get_field('cpd_credits');
                                $total_credit += $cur_credit;
                        ?>


                        <?php endwhile; else : ?>
                        <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

                        <tr>
                            <td <?php if($total_credit >= 2): ?> style="background-color:#009137;" <?php endif; ?> <?php if($total_credit < 2): ?> style="background-color:#f50c1a;" <?php endif; ?>>
                                Total: <?php echo $total_credit;?> of 2 in the last 12 months
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        </table>

                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <!-- END OF MEMBERSHIP D -->




                        <!-- MEMBERSHIP E -->                       

                    <?php if( rcp_is_active() && 6 == rcp_get_subscription_id() ) : ?>

                        <?php
                        $post_list = new wp_query( $post_args ); ?>

                            <table style="width:100%">      
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Compliance</td>
                                </tr>

                                <?php
                                    if( $post_list->have_posts() ) : while( $post_list->have_posts() ) : $post_list->the_post();
                                ?>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
                                        <td><?php the_field('cpd_credits'); ?></td>
                                    </tr>

                    <?php endwhile; else : ?>
                    <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>


                    <?php

                    $total_credit = 0;

                    $post_list = new wp_query( $post_args ); ?>

                    <table style="width:100%">      

                        <?php
                            if( $post_list->have_posts() ) : while( $post_list->have_posts() ) : $post_list->the_post();
                                $cur_credit = get_field('cpd_credits');
                                $total_credit += $cur_credit;
                        ?>


                        <?php endwhile; else : ?>
                        <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

                        <tr>
                            <td <?php if($total_credit >= 2): ?> style="background-color:#009137;" <?php endif; ?> <?php if($total_credit < 2): ?> style="background-color:#f50c1a;" <?php endif; ?>>
                                Total: <?php echo $total_credit;?> of 2 in the last 12 months
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        </table>

                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <!-- END OF MEMBERSHIP E -->


                        <!-- END OF COMPLIANCE-->


            </div>  

            <?php }?>




             <?php $pl_args = array(
                 'base'     => add_query_arg('paged','%#%'),
                 'format'   => '',
                 'total'    => floor($total_users / $number),
                 'current'  => max(1, $paged),
              );

              // for ".../page/n"
              if($GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->using_permalinks())
                $pl_args['base'] = user_trailingslashit(trailingslashit(get_pagenum_link(1)).'page/%#%/', 'paged');

              echo paginate_links($pl_args);?>

            </div>
```